# SQL Server Table Size Discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, size

Hopefully this has a simple answer and I've missed something obvious. I have a table where the number of rows * the row size is much smaller then the actual data space used by the table.

If I run the standard report "Disk Usage by Top Tables", the numbers I get are:

```
# Records   Reserved (KB)      Data (KB)      Indexes (KB)      Unused (KB) 
33,245        32,962,192       31,070,264       144               1,891,784
```

which (unless I'm missing something) implies each row is taking up just under 1MB!

The table schema (which I didn't design) is:

```
CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable]
(
    [Code]     [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [SomeID]   [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SomeID1]  [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Updated]  [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SomeId2]  [int] NULL,
    [SomeId3]  [int] NULL,
    [Somekey]  [real] NULL,
    [desc1]    [char](12) NULL,
    [colA]     [real] NULL,
    [someid4]  [char](20) NULL,
    [starttime] [real] NULL,
    [endtime]  [real] NULL,
    [duration] [real] NULL,
    [reason]   [real] NULL,
    [status]   [real] NULL,
    [category] [real] NULL,
    [comment]  [char](30) NULL,
    [ColB]     [real] NULL,
    [ColC]     [real] NULL
)
```

It has no indexes or keys.

A bit of research lead me to the idea that perhaps in the past the table had variable length columns that had been deleted, so I ran [DBCC CLEANTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with no change.

SQL Server 2005 x64 Service Pack 3 (as far as I can work out from the following version string:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (X64)   May 26 2009 14:13:01   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)]

**Update**: I'm fairly sure this is due to a pathologically fragmented HEAP ....
I rebuilt by applying a clustered index (an index is required, according to missing index reports), and the size discrepancy has gone.

Comment: Can you check the physical table layout? see http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you delete from heaps, allocated space may not be unallocated unless you use a table lock.
See "Deleting Rows from a Heap" from [DELETE on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

This is a separate problem to fragmentation (which happens of course)

Just in case, have you tried this to update usage info?

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'MySchema.MyTable', 'true'
```

With no indexes or keys, you can't defragment it normally. 
You can add/drop a clustered index, or do something like this

```
SELECT * INTO [MySchema].[MyTableNew] 
FROM [MySchema].[MyTable]
-- ORDER BY something

-- if you like
EXEC sp_spaceused 'MySchema.MyTableNew', 'true'

DROP TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable];

EXEC sp_rename 'MySchema.MyTableNew', 'MyTable';
```

oops: just seen updates, my Internets has been broken on and off...

Comment: was closest answer to what I ended doing (I actually created a clustered index: there was no reason why this table was a heap, and a missing index was needed in a range search)

Answer (score 2):

I use this script:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
 (  [Table_Name] varchar(50),
    Row_Count int,
    Table_Size varchar(50),
    Data_Space_Used varchar(50),
    Index_Space_Used varchar(50),
    Unused_Space varchar(50) )
INSERT INTO #temp exec sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused "?"'

SELECT Table_Name AS [Table], Row_Count AS [Row Count],
        dbo.strip_kb(Table_Size) / 1024 AS [Table size],
        dbo.strip_kb(Data_Space_Used) / 1024 AS [Data Space],
        dbo.strip_kb(Index_Space_Used) / 1024 AS [Index Space],
        dbo.strip_kb(Unused_Space) / 1024 AS [Unused Space],
        CASE Row_Count WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE dbo.strip_kb(Data_Space_Used) * 1024 / Row_Count END AS [Avg Row Size]
    FROM #temp order by Row_Count DESC

DROP TABLE #temp
```

It gives you the average row size per table, as well as the data you showed above, but I tend to trust its output a bit more than the built-in reports :)

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew the sizes...THe built-in reports seem pretty good. I'd be surprised if they weren't using something similiar...